# Is there any logging for cloud deployed API? If yes, how to check those?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, monitoring, apifunction

I am testing using `CloudDeploy[APIFunction[...]]`.  I can not find any info about real time logging.

If there is any problem happening with the cloud deployed API, how can I debug it?

Comment: No, there isn't any out of the box feature for logging afaik.

Comment: @kuba,  Thanks for answer.

Comment: p.s. there are server level logs but I don't think they are accessible in the public cloud.

Answer (score 2):

I will show you a small piece of code you can use as a starting point, it is already nice enough.

Just compose `withLogger[apiPath]` with your APIFunction's function. And initialize the log file.

Like this:

```
With[{apiPath = "api/foo"},

 CloudPut["#API init " <> DateString[], apiPath <> ".log"];

 CloudDeploy[
   APIFunction[
     {"x" -> "Integer"}
   , withLogger[apiPath] @ Check[ (*!*)
       Print["start"]
     ; 1 / Echo[#x]
     , GenerateHTTPResponse[Echo @ HTTPErrorResponse[500]]
     ] &
   ]
 , apiPath
 , Permissions -> "Public"
 ]

]

(*! - only that line matters, everything else is only to show the point*)
```

`withLogger` is defined at the end of the post. Here is an example:

[image]

```
withLogger[parentPath_] := Function[expr,
  Module[{logFile, log, res, timeMark},

   timeMark = AbsoluteTime[];

   logFile = parentPath <> ".log";

   Quiet@OpenAppend[logFile, FormatType -> (OutputForm), 
     PageWidth -> Infinity];

   log[type : "INFO" | "DEBUG" | "MESSAGE" : "INFO", msg__] := Write[
     logFile,
     DateString[{"ISODate", " ", "Time", ".", "Millisecond", " "}],
     $SessionID, " ",
 $RequesterWolframID, " ",
     type, " ",
     Sequence @@ Riffle[{msg}, " "]
     ];

   Block[{Print, Echo, messageString},
    Print = log;
    Echo[input_, label_: "", pipe_: Identity] := CompoundExpression[
      Print["INFO", label /. "" :> (## &[]), pipe@input],
      input
      ];

    messageString[
      Hold[Message[msg : MessageName[head_, name_], args___], _]] := 
     ToString[StringForm[msg /. Messages[head], args]];

    Internal`HandlerBlock[
     {"Message", If[Last[#], Print["MESSAGE", messageString[#]]] &},
     Print["--------------- API CALL EXECUTION --------------"];
     res = expr;
     Print@
      StringTemplate["Kernel evaluation time `` [s]"][
       AbsoluteTime[] - timeMark];
     res
     ]
    ]
   ]
  , HoldAllComplete
  ]
```